# How to get bootstrap collapse accordion panel to close when another is opened?

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

This is my accordion:

```
<div class="subdiv-wrapper">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion1_{{subdivIndex}}" ng-repeat="admin in subdivisions" ng-init="subdivIndex = $index">
        <div class="panel panel-default" id="accordion1_{{subdivIndex}}" ng-repeat="admin2 in admin.province">

            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="accordion1_{{subdivIndex}}" href="#collapse-1{{subdivIndex}}" aria-expanded="false" ><span class="span-left">{{ admin2.name }}</span><span class="span-right">{{ admin2.population }}</span></a>
                </h4>
            </div>

            <div id="collapse-1{{subdivIndex}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <h3>districts</h3>
                    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion2_{{subdivIndex}}">

                        <!-- districts -->
                        <div class="panel panel-default" ng-repeat="admin3 in admin.district" ng-init="subdivIndex2 = $index">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">
                                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2_{{subdivIndex}}" href="#collapse-1-1_{{subdivIndex}}_{{subdivIndex2}}"><span class="span-left">{{ admin3.name }}</span><span class="span-right" aria-expanded="false">{{ admin3.population }}</span></a> 
                                </h4>
                            </div>
                            <!-- communes -->                           
                            <div id="collapse-1-1_{{subdivIndex}}_{{subdivIndex2}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                                <div class="panel-body">
                                    <!-- display 'communes' title here -->
                                    <div ng-repeat="admin4 in admin3.commune"><span class="span-left">{{ admin4.name }}</span><span class="span-right">{{ admin4.population }}</span></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                         
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment, it doesn't function like the usual bootstrap accordion would, each 'province' panel stays open until you click it again. It doesn't automatically close when another panel is opened. Also the inner pannels (districts) don't close when the parent panel (province) is closed.

I've seen people use data-target with the panel's id to make this work but i'm not sure how to use it with the dynamic $indexes i'm using.

Comment: It seems like applying `id="accordion1_{{subdivIndex}}"` to both the parent element and the first panel. Since you need to target this ID with `data-parent` to create the behavior you desire, duplicate IDs is probably what's causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did what you said, removed the duplicate id from the parent element and also noticed there was a '#' missing by mistake so added it back in. But its still unfortunately exactly the same. Do you know what else could be causing this issue?

Comment: At this point I would say: Show us the semi-functional code.  What you have on StackOverflow looks like you have some nested accordion menus.

Comment: I recreated another version here: https://plnkr.co/edit/VDn4Kprz6hd9pEaGHBkk?p=preview this time the outer accordion (provinces) is working ok, but the inner nested accordion (districts) is not. I think it has something to do with the $index. I might have to write some javascript to make the inner accordion work like the outer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/SgOFaUNw7EQFxYz3RWPB?p=preview

```css
#accordion-wrapper {
 width: 400px; position: absolute; left: 50%; margin-left: -200px; top: 20%;
}

.panel {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}


.panel-heading {
 border-radius: 0px;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}

.panel-title {
 width: 100%;
 text-decoration: none;
 border: none;
 background: #9bdbe6;
}
.panel-title:focus {
 outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js'></script>

  </head>
  <body>
  
    <div ng-app="algeriaApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">


      <div id="accordion-wrapper">

        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel" ng-repeat="sub in subdivisions" ng-init="provIndex = $index" >


            <!--  Province Heading -->
            <div class="panel-heading" ng-repeat="prov in sub.province" >

              <button class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="closeinner($event)" data-target="#sliding-content_{{provIndex}}" data-parent="#accordion" aria-expanded="false">{{prov.name}}</button>
              
            </div> <!-- end panel-heading -->

        <!-- Province Sliding content -->

            <div id="sliding-content_{{provIndex}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" >
                
               <div class="panel-body"> 

                <!-- ========== INNER ACCORDION ========== -->
                <div class="panel-group" id="inner-accordion">
                  <div class="panel" ng-repeat="dist in sub.district" ng-init="distIndex = $index" >

                    <!-- District Heading (inner accordion) -->

                    <div class="panel-heading">

                      <button class="panel-title" data-toggle="collapse" ng-click="clickcollapse($event)" data-target="#sliding-content_{{provIndex}}_{{distIndex}}" data-parent="inner_accordion" aria-expanded="false" style="background:#d0dae0">{{dist.name}}</button>

                    </div> <!-- end panel-heading -->

                    <!-- District Sliding content (inner accordion ) communes list -->

                    <div id="sliding-content_{{provIndex}}_{{distIndex}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" >
                      <div class="panel-body"> 

                        <p>placeholder</p>
                        <!-- list of communes will be displayed here -->

                      </div>
                    </div>

                  </div> <!-- end panel (individual districts)-->
                </div> <!-- end panel-group / inner accordion -->


               </div> <!-- end panel-body -->

            </div> <!-- end province slidig content -->


          
          </div> <!-- end panel (individual provinces) -->
        </div> <!-- end panel-group -->


      </div> <!-- end wrapper -->

    </div> <!-- end algeriaApp -->

<script type="text/javascript">

  var algeriaApp = angular.module('algeriaApp', []);

  algeriaApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.subdivisions = [
       //start province: adrar
       { "province": [{"name":"Adrar","population":"123"}], "district": [
          
          { "name": "Adrar1", "population":"1234"},
          { "name": "Adrar2", "population":"1234"},
          { "name": "Adrar3", "population":"1234"}

        ] }, //end province: adrar


       //start province: algiers
       { "province": [{"name":"Algiers","population":"123"}], "district": [
          
          { "name": "Algiers1", "population":"1234"},
          { "name": "Algiers2", "population":"1234"},
          { "name": "Algiers3", "population":"1234"}

        ] }, //end province: algiers

       //start province: algiers
       { "province": [{"name":"Chlef","population":"123"}], "district": [
          
          { "name": "Chlef1", "population":"1234"},
          { "name": "Chlef2", "population":"1234"},
          { "name": "Chlef3", "population":"1234"}

        ] } //end province: algiers

     ]; // end subdivisions 


      $scope.clickcollapse = function(e) {
        $('#inner-accordion .collapse.in').collapse('hide')
      };

      $scope.closeinner = function(e) {
        $('#inner-accordion .collapse.in').collapse('hide')
      }

  });

</script>

  </body>
</html>
```